# comparing two arrays of integers in c acts odd

Tags: c, arrays

Here is part of my code , I read some fields of a kernel data structure and compare it with an array. but oddly I see that when I print contents of array `orig_poolinfo` the first element is 103 though it is actually 128.

```
int get_poolinfo_fields(vmi_instance_t vmi)
{
int orig_poolinfo[]={128,103,76,51,25,1,32,26,20,14,7,1};
uint64_t poolinfo_table_addr = 0xffffffff81ca4fc0;//kernel 3.11 
int poolinfo_table;
int i;

  //for( i=0;i<12;i++)
    //    printf("poolinfo_table=%d %d\n",i,orig_poolinfo[i]);
  for( i=0;i<12;i++)
     {
        vmi_read_64_va(vmi,poolinfo_table_addr, 0, &poolinfo_table);
        printf("poolinfo_table=%d orig_poolinfo[%d]=%d\n",poolinfo_table,i,orig_poolinfo[i]);
        if(poolinfo_table != orig_poolinfo[i])
           printf("hi\n");//return(1);
        poolinfo_table_addr = poolinfo_table_addr + 0x4;
     }
return(0);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
poolinfo_table=128 orig_poolinfo[0]=103
hi
poolinfo_table=103 orig_poolinfo[1]=103
poolinfo_table=76 orig_poolinfo[2]=76
poolinfo_table=51 orig_poolinfo[3]=51
poolinfo_table=25 orig_poolinfo[4]=25
poolinfo_table=1 orig_poolinfo[5]=1
poolinfo_table=32 orig_poolinfo[6]=32
poolinfo_table=26 orig_poolinfo[7]=26
poolinfo_table=20 orig_poolinfo[8]=20
poolinfo_table=14 orig_poolinfo[9]=14
poolinfo_table=7 orig_poolinfo[10]=7
poolinfo_table=1 orig_poolinfo[11]=1
```

Comment: Minimal test case please.

Comment: Pardon me, but the name `vmi_read_64_va` implies that this function reads 8 bytes of data. Now, by reading those 8 bytes into the 4-byte variable `poolinfo_table`, you are essentially triggering undefined behavior. My guess is that in practice, you are overriding the value of the next variable in the stack, which happens to be `i`, hence, printing `orig_poolinfo[i]` gives you the value of the second entry in this array instead of the value of the first entry (just a guess though, which doesn't quite explain how `i` is not being overridden in subsequent iterations of the loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different types int and uint64_t. Their sizes might not be the same.

By using `vmi_read_64_va()` you copy 8 bytes. If sizeof( int ) is 4 on your system you get undefined behavior. This means anything can happen and your program is not behaving correctly.

Use functions appropriate to your type size and don't mix types.